# Recursive Tree for T(n)=T(n/2)+T(n/3)+1

Tags: recursion, tree, complexity-theory, relation

I found a recursive tree for T(n)=T(n/2)+T(n/3)+n but still am confused about how the recursive tree is with a cost of 1 at each level.

what is its height?

How many nodes it has at the last level?

Comment: For defining a recursive formula, you must also give the inductive terms: For example `T(0) = ?`. Otherwise, this recursion is meaningless.

Comment: @DanielHeilper thank you for your response. yes, you are right, T(0)=1